# Use Underscore/Lodash to sort an object by values into an array of pairs for AngularJS ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, lodash

I want to put the information in the following object on the front end using Angular's ng-repeat.  I need to order the key/value pairs by value and display them in that order in an array from the top down.

I have the following objects:

```
{name: 32, name1: 7, name2: 83, name3: 19}
```

I want to display something on the front end kind of like this:

name2: 83
name: 32
name3: 19
name1: 7

with the key/value pairs sorted in order of the values. I'm sure there is a simple way of doing this but I have yet to perceive it.

Comment: First produce an array of `[key, value]` arrays out of it, then sort it.

Comment: @zerkms, I did that part but I can't figure out how to sort it from here. Sorry so slow.

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy

Comment: I didn't see how to apply it at first _.sortBy(_.pairs(topRedemptions), function(n){return n[1]}) works though

Comment: show what you tried, don't just ask `how`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't sort an object but by converting it into an array you can easily sort it:

```
var obj = {name: 32, name1: 7, name2: 83, name3: 19};
var pairs = _.pairs(obj);
var sortedPairs = _.sortBy(pairs, function (p) {return -p[1]});
console.log(sortedPairs);
```

The next step is to show them:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in sortedPairs">
    {{item[0]}}: {{item[1]}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing I need it in descending order!